# New Genoil Miner on Ubuntu - How Does this Start? I Only See Windows Instructions

Tags: genoil

Entering any of this into terminal doesn't get it mining. I have NEVER figured out how to get Genoil mining (I'm on Ubuntu). Where is this information entered and how does the mining get started?

[image: Screenshot of What I don't know how to start Genoil with]

Answer (score 0):

1. make a script file:

   Open a terminal and enter

   :~$ gedit mine-eth.sh
2. cope and paste all the command into the file, make sure you add this on the first line of the file and paste everything from the next line:

   #! /bin/bash
3. save and close the file.
4. back to terminal, enter this:

   :~$ chmod +x mine-eth.sh
5. still in the terminal:

   :~$ sudo ./mine-eth.sh

Enter your password when prompt and enter again, Now you should see some output.

Comment: After the ccp-ethereum directory installed and build is done WHERE is the mine-eth.sh file stored? I'm getting ... 
./mn.sh: line 2: setx: command not found
./mn.sh: line 3: setx: command not found
./mn.sh: line 4: setx: command not found
./mn.sh: line 5: setx: command not found
./mn.sh: line 6: setx: command not found
Invalid argument: -S

Comment: Thank for your responses but that returns... $ sudo ./mine-eth.sh
./mine-eth.sh: line 2: export: `0': not a valid identifier
./mine-eth.sh: line 3: export: `100': not a valid identifier
./mine-eth.sh: line 4: export: `1': not a valid identifier
./mine-eth.sh: line 5: export: `100': not a valid identifier
./mine-eth.sh: line 6: export: `100': not a valid identifier
Invalid argument: -S

Comment: Sorry my bad, it looks like you are using setx which is for windows, edit your file and delete all the "setx" and try again.

Comment: Here is [link](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/7164/mining-ethereum-problem) a problem almost identical to yours.